# Error while compiling Composer

Tags: php, compiler-errors, composer-php, cpanel

I am running cPanel and I want to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). I attempted to install it and found an error while running this,

```
root@server [/bin]# php installer --check
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:
PHP was compiled with --with-curlwrappers which will cause issues with HTTP authentication and GitHub.
Recompile it without this flag if possible
```

Can I safely ignore this error? What issue may I come across in the future?

Comment: Use easyapache3 or easyapache4 for recompiling or uninstall rpm of CurlWrappers.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to always (re)compile PHP. For me it was sufficient to install php5-curl and restart Apache:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: In Cpanel it is highly recommended to use the official roads, using Esaypache3 or Easyapache4. This way you ensure that in future no breaks actualziaciones the system, and remain as you want. Please do not give advice so lightly. 
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/EasyApache+3.30+Release+Notes